# how to extract only values in first column for tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am getting an error when I return a tensor
final_layer_score to the output ranking function. The problem is the each element gives five different scores so the shape of the output is [703150,5] and I need it to be [703150,1]. How can I extract the first value.
For example:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3, 4],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7, 8],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12]],
       [[12, 13, 14, 15,16],
        [16, 17, 18, 19,17],
        [20, 21, 22, 23,18]]])
# I want to only get [0,4,8,12,16,20]
```

Gives this:

```
    Cannot reshape a tensor with 3515750 elements to shape [28126,25,1]
(703150 elements) for '{{node/accumulate_scores/Reshape}} = 
Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](noe/group_score/strided_slice, 
groupwise_dnn_v2/node/strided_slice_1)' with input shapes: [703150,5], [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If shape is [703150,5]:

```
a = tf.random.uniform((703150, 5), 0, 10, dtype = tf.int32)
tf.expand_dims(a[:,0], 1)
```

If shape is [x, 3, 5] as in example:

```
a = tf.random.uniform((1234, 3, 5), 0, 10, dtype = tf.int32)
tf.expand_dims(tf.reshape(a[:,:,0], -1, 1), 1)
```

Comment: What is the tf.expand_dims(a[:,0], 1) second argument 1 in expand_dims?

Comment: Because you asked for the shape [703150, 1]. If [703150] works equally well you don't need the expand_dims calls.

Comment: Thanks in the second case why do you need -1,1 as second and third arguments? tf.expand_dims(tf.reshape(a[:,:,0], -1, 1), 1)  Sorry I find tensor flow pretty confusing.

Comment: Because `a[:,:,0]` is a 2-dimensional array. It needs to be flattened.